# Listar colunas de acordo com a data atual

Tags: mysql, query, view

Tenho a seguinte view:

```
select * from chamdosrow
```

Ela retorna da seguinte forma:

```
NOME    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
MARCOS  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
PAULO   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
JOAO    0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
JOSE    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
VITOR   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
DANIEL  0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
CAIO    0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
MARCEL  0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
PEDRO   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

As colunas:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
```

Referencia-se as datas do mês,o que preciso é que só liste as colunas do 1 dia até o dia atual, como poderia fazer isso ?

Comment: Para selecionar uma lista de colunas dinamicamente você vai precisar de uma query dinâmica. Uma outra solução poderia usar pivot. Uma melhor ainda seria criar uma modelagem de dados melhor

Comment: Você vai executar isso via programa? Qual linguagem? Tem algum trecho de código inicial? Assim podemos te ajudar a montar a query dinâmica como bem sugerido pelo @jean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O melhor seria mesmo rever o modelo de dados mas, se deseja mesmo prosseguir, fica aqui uma opção:

```
SET @DiaHoje := DAY(CURDATE());

SELECT CONCAT('SELECT nome, ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', c.COLUMN_NAME, '`')), ' FROM chamdosrow;')
INTO @query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'chamdosrow'
  AND CAST(c.COLUMN_NAME AS UNSIGNED) <= @DiaHoje
ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION;

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

É bastante simples, mas se desejar, posso deixar aqui uma explicação. Fica aqui também o habitual [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da377c/12)

O exemplo em cima funciona quando acede directamente a uma tabela, no seu caso, e porque está a aceder a uma view, pode fazer da seguinte forma, para obter o nome das colunas dinamicamente:

```
SET @DiaHoje := DAY(CURDATE());

SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', Dia, '`')), ' FROM chamdosrow;')
INTO @query
FROM (
  SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS Dia 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t1,
  (SELECT @row:=0) r 
) DiasMes       
WHERE Dia <= @DiaHoje
ORDER BY Dia;

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Fica aqui o Segundo [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77708/7).

Answer (score 2):

Uma abordagem com uma lógica um pouco menos complexa, manipulando uma lista com o nome dos campos igualmente espaçados:

```
SELECT CONCAT( 
   'SELECT nome, ',
    SUBSTRING(
         ' 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31', 
         1, 
         (DAY(CURDATE())*3)-1
    ),
    ' FROM chamdosrow '
) INTO @query FROM dual;

PREPARE st FROM @query;
EXECUTE st;
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução similar a do Gustavo, mas sem ter que listar todos campos (um detalhe, alterei os campos de 1 a 9, colocando um zero na frente):

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'SELECT ',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`') ORDER BY column_name),
      ',',
      day(curdate())),
    ' FROM tabela'
  )
FROM
  information_schema.columns 
WHERE
  table_schema=DATABASE() 
  AND table_name='tabela'
INTO @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Veja no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c3f9/2)